# What is the term for an incorrect word used in a sentence

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

My brain has drawn a blank.   What is an adjective I can use to describe someone's use of a word that is similarly spelled, but not even close in definition to the word they intended to use.

Example:

> I don't take myself too seriously but I can be a bit of a
>   ***contraction*** at times, a good or bad person.

I am almost positive they were going for something along the lines of "***contradiction***".

Answer (score 2):

I would rather define such an act as "malapropism"(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/malapropism).

However, if we look at the adjective "malapropos", then we find (as per the Merriam-Webster) that it is not pertinent specifically to the awry placement of words but refers to the misplacement of things in general (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/malapropos).

Comment: +1 for Malapropism.  I’m not sure what your intent is in the second paragraph though.

Comment: @Jim Yes, the second paragraph would seem superfluous. *Malapropos* certainly exists as adverb, adjective and noun - but *Malapropism* refers specifically to an incorrect, but similar-sounding word, - after Sheridan's character, *Mrs Malaprop*, who tended to do that.  *After dinner they danced the flamingo*. *The Prime Minister was challenged in the House of Columns*.

Comment: The O.P. wanted us to provide him with a particular "adjective" which correctly expounds his statement. The first paragraph corresponds to a "noun" and in the second paragraph, I am providing its adjective( with a caution that malapropos digresses slightly and encompasses more things than words only).